# CSS seems to think :not overrides things after it?

Tags: css, google-chrome

So , I have this CSS code:

```
form input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="file"]), form select, form textarea {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    /*other stuff removed for irrelevance*/
}

form input[type="tel"] {
    width: calc(100% - 22px - 50px);
}
```

and, in Chrome, the developer tools say that the width is being set by the right thing, but disabling the first selector set's `width` or changing `form input[type="tel"]` to `form input[type="tel"]:not([type="file"])` fixes the width.

What could possibly be causing this insanity? Is it a bug, or am I just missing something?

Comment: `form input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="file"])` is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `form input[type="tel"]`

Answer (score 1):

its the selector hierarchy amount. one element selector + 2 type selector is more powerful than one element selector + 1 type selector.